# Finding FORTRAN array location, 4-dimensional array

Tags: arrays, location, fortran

Hey guys, I have a question. 
If given a four dimensional array in FORTRAN, and told to find a location of a certain part of it (with a starting location of 200 and 4 bytes per integer). Is there a formula to find the location if is stored in row-major and column-major order.

 

Basiically given array A(x:X, y:Y, z:Z, q:q) and told to find the location at A(a,b,c,d) what is the formula for finding the location

Comment: What constitutes a location?  The memory address?  The relation to adjacent elements?  The offset from the beginning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes up all the time when using C libraries with Fortran -- eg, calling MPI routines trying to send particular subsets of Fortran arrays.

Fortran is <strike>row-major, or</strike> more usefully, the first index moves fastest.  That is, the item after A(1,2,3,4) in linear order in memory is A(2,2,3,4).  So in your example above, an increase in a by one is a jump of 1 index in the array; a jump in b by one corresponds to a jump of (X-x+1); a jump in c by one corresponds to a jump of (X-x+1)x(Y-y+1), and a jump in d by one is a jump of (X-x+1)x(Y-y+1)x(Z-z+1).     In C-based languages, it would be just the opposite; a jump of 1 in the d index would move you 1 index in memory; a jump in c would be a jump of (Q-q+1), etc.

If you have m indicies, and n<sub>i</sub> is the (zero-based) index in the i<sup>th</sup> index from the left, and that index has a range of N<sub>i</sub>, then the (zero-based) index from the starting position is something like this:

[image]

where the product is 1 if the upper index is less than the lower index.   To find the number of bytes from the start of the array, you'd multiply that by the size of the object, eg 4 bytes for 32-bit integers.

Comment: Actually, Fortran is column-major and C row-major by the usual definition of those terms.

Comment: Ack, and there was a typo in my LaTeX, too.   Time to put down the keyboard for the day, I think.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, couldn't find that formula.Thanks so much and thanks for the other responses guys

Answer (score 2):

Been over 25 years since I did any FORTRAN.

I believe FORTRAN, unlike many other languages, lays arrays out in
column major order. That means the leftmost index is the
one that changes most frequently when processing a multi
dimensional array in linear order. Once
the maximum dimension of the leftmost index is reached, set it back to 1, assuming 1 based
indexing, and increment the next level index by 1 and start the process over again.

To calculate the index configuration for any given address offset
you need to know the value of each of the 4 array dimensions.  Without this
you can't do it.

**Example:**

Suppose your array has dimensions 2 by 3 by 4 by 5. This implies a
total of 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 = 120 cells in the matrix. You want the index corresponding
to the 200th byte.
This would be the (200 / 4) - 1 = 49th cell (this assumes 4 bytes per cell and offset zero
is the first cell).

First observe how specific indices translate into offsets...

What cell number does the element X(1,1,1,1) occur at? Simple answer: 1
What cell number does element X(1, 2, 1, 1) occur at? Since we cycled through
the leftmost dimension it must be that dimension plus 1. In other words,
2 + 1 = 3. How about X(1, 1, 2, 1)? We cycled trough the first two dimensions
which is 2 * 3 = 6 plus 1 to give us 7. Finally X(1, 1, 1, 2) must be:
2 * 3 * 4 = 24 plus 1 gives the 25th cell.

Notice that the next righmost index does not increment until the cell number
exceeds the product of the indices to its left. Using this observation you can
calculate the indices for any given cell number by working from the rightmost
index to the left most as follows:

Right most index increments every (2 * 3 * 4 = 24) cells. 24 goes into 49 (the cell number
we want to find the indexing for) twice
leaving 1 left over. Add 1 (for 1 based indexing) that gives us a rightmost
index value of 2 + 1 = 3. Next index (moving left) changes every (2 * 3 = 12) cells. One goes into 12
zero times, this gives us index 0 + 1 = 1. Next index changes every 2 cells. One goes into 2 zero
times giving an incex value of 1. For the last (leftmost index) just add 1 to whatever is
left over, 1 + 1 = 2. This gives us the following reference X(2, 1, 1, 2).

Double check by working it back to an offset:

((2 - 1) + ((1 - 1) * 2) + ((1 - 1) * 2 * 3) + ((3 - 1) * 2 * 3 * 4) = 49.

Just change the numbers and use the same process for any number of dimensions
and/or offsets.

Answer (score 1):

Fortran has column-major order for arrays.   This is described at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order#Column-major_order.   Further down in that article there is the equation for the memory offset of a higher dimensional array.