# 1 dimensional array for indexing a 3D matrix

Tags: c, indexing, fortran

I'm trying to write a linear index for 3D matrix. Is there a formula to determine what is the linear index of `(i,j,k)` th element in a matrix with `(nx,ny,nz)` dimensions?
Is there any difference whether I'm using `C` of `FORTRAN` or something else?
I searched for similar questions but nothing was founded .
Thanks for any guide.

Comment: How do you define linear index? Are you familiar with terms row-major order and C-major order?

Comment: Yes,I think Fortran is row major, now I use Fortran.

Comment: if you are using a 1d array and doing your own index arithmetic you can choose whichever index scheme you like.

Comment: Some of the previous questions/answers on this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20316302/c-fortran-2d-arrays-basic/20319026#20319026, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664110/row-major-versus-column-major-layout-of-matrices, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809200/finding-fortran-array-location-4-dimensional-array/5810475#5810475

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, Fortran is column major order. That means that when linearly indexing a multidimensional array the first index grows faster, i.e.

```
  ind(i,j,k) = i + (j-1)*nx + (k-1)*ny*nx
```

where I assume indexing from 1. The function `ind` gives an index the element `(i,j,k)` would have when looking at the same as a one-dimensional array (e.g., in sequence association).

Most other languages, including C derivatives, use the row-major order, so that the last index grows the fastest. They also index from 0.

```
  ind(i,j,k) = k + j*nz + i*ny*nz
```

There are also other differences — the multidimensional arrays are actually arrays of arrays (similar to pointers to pointers) in C.